# Delphi UDF function to C

Tags: c, delphi, date, types, udf

I'm trying to rewrite the following UDF function from Delphi to C but I don't know which parameter type should I use instead of PISC_QUAD and how to extract the month number from the param value.

```
function GetMonthShortName(ib_date: PISC_QUAD): PAnsiChar; cdecl; export;
var
  tm_date: tm;
begin
  isc_decode_date(ib_date, @tm_date);
  case tm_date.tm_mon of
     0: result := PAnsiChar('Jan');
     1: result := PAnsiChar('Feb');
     2: result := PAnsiChar('Mar');
     3: result := PAnsiChar('Apr');
     4: result := PAnsiChar('May');
     5: result := PAnsiChar('June');
     6: result := PAnsiChar('July');
     7: result := PAnsiChar('Aug');
     8: result := PAnsiChar('Sept');
     9: result := PAnsiChar('Oct');
    10: result := PAnsiChar('Nov');
    11: result := PAnsiChar('Dec');
    else result:=nil;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PISC_QUAD` is `^ISC_QUAD`. That is, pointer to `ISC_QUAD`.

In C that would be `ISC_QUAD*`.

Extract the month number in the exact same way. Call `isc_decode_date` passing the `ISC_QUAD*` as input and then read the `tm_mon` field of the output struct.

```
int getMonth(ISC_QUAD *ib_date)
{
    struct tm tm_date;
    isc_decode_date(ibdate, &tm_date);
    return tm_date.tm_mon;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for silence. I just need to test this and I can't do it today. Be patient please.